# Jenkins - check Git before every builds

Tags: java, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am currently setting up a Continuous Integration system with Jenkins, and I came across a problem :

Almost every project depends on others projects. So, in order to perform daily builds, I use the [CloudBees Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin). It does its job pretty nicely actually, but not in an optimal way : It builds EVERY jobs I tell it to, without even checking on Git if there are any changes. So I would like to know if there are any ways to force Jenkins to check on Git if there are any changes before actually building the project.

PS : Sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker

Comment: you mean the actual project source is in git?

Comment: No, Git is used in its intended way : We use git commit and git push to update our sources. And with a plugin, Jenkins can use Git as a SCM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I chose to stick to BuildFlow and the Groovy language, instead of using scripts, but it's just by convenience, and this solution would totally work with shell language. Moreover, using BuildFlow allows you to use Parallel(), to start multiple jobs at the same time.

Here's my solution :

I found the plugin [Jenkins Poll SCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin), that polls the SCM before trying to build it (only if necessary).

The only problem with [CloudBees Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) is that it does not wait for previous jobs to be completed, as I am not using the build() method. To overcome this problem, I made my own buildWithPolling() method, that waits for the job to be done before going on. The only downside of my method is that it does not wait for downstream jobs to be finished (But I don't know if it does with the build() method either...). Here is the code of my method :

```
def buildWithPolling(project)
{
    //Connection to the URL starting the polling, and starting the building if needed
    def address = "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/" + project + "/poll"
    println "Connexion à " + address + " pour scrutation du Git et build si besoin est."
    def poll = new URL(address)
    poll.openStream()

    //Declaration of variables used to know if the build is still running, or if it is finished
    boolean inProgress = true
    def parser = new XmlParser()
    def rootNode = null;
    address = "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/" + project + "/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=1&tree=building&xpath=*/building"

    while(inProgress) {
        //A 5 seconds pause, because we don't need to overload the server
        sleep(5000)  
        //Request sent to the server, to know if the job is finished.
        def baos =new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        baos << new URL(address).openStream()
        rootNode = parser.parseText(new String(baos.toByteArray()))
        inProgress = rootNode.text().toBoolean()
    }
}
```

It is probaly not the best solution, but it's working for me !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you have looked at the configs in the job settings. There is a place to force a fresh checkout. I have svn linked, similar thing will be with git

[image]

If not you can looking for adding manual commands as shown below. Check to see if you can arrange the order of this to execute first then build your task

[image]

Comment: Sadly, Jenkins does not support Git on its own, and you have to install a plugin in order to use it. And this plugin does not have this option

Comment: I think it is the best solution. I'll explain the solution I found in an answer